# To 'this' or not to 'this'?

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, functional-programming, homework, comparative-review

I was given a homework and I have 2 solutions: one that uses `this` and other one that doesn't.

I [tested both solutions on jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/this-or-no-this) but sometimes it says the version with `this` is faster or sometimes the other one. So I think I cannot really rely on jsPerf. Anyway, should performance be always the top priority?

By the way, here is the problem statement:

> Write a function `addg` that adds from many invocations, until it sees an empty invocation.
>
> Something like:
>
> addg();                // undefined
>
> addg(2)();             // 2
>
> addg(2)(7)();          // 9
>
> addg(3)(0)();          // 3
>
> addg(1)(2)(4)(8)();    // 15
>
> addg(5)(4)(-2)();      // 7

Here are my 2 solutions:

1. version with `this`:

```js
function add(a,b){
  return a+b;
}

function addg(val){
  var numbers = [];

  this.addToCollection = function(val){
    numbers.push(val);

    if(typeof val !== 'number'){  // in case of ()
      var sum = 0, 
          l = numbers.length;

      numbers.forEach(function(num, i){
        if(i === l-1){
          return;
        } else {
          sum = add(sum, num);
        }
      });

//       console.log(numbers);

      if(numbers.length === 1 && numbers[0] === undefined){
        return undefined;
      } else {
        return sum;        
      }

    } else {  // in case of (n)
      return this.addToCollection;  // return the function each time so you can apply it to other numbers in the chain      
    }

  };

  return this.addToCollection(val);
}

console.log(addg());                // undefined
console.log(addg(2)());             // 2
console.log(addg(2)(7)());          // 9
console.log(addg(3)(0)());          // 7
console.log(addg(1)(2)(4)(8)());    // 15
console.log(addg(5)(4)(-2)());      // 7
```

2. version without `this`:

```js
function add(a,b){
  return a+b;
}

function addg(val){
  var numbers = [];

  function addValues(val){
    numbers.push(val);

    if(typeof val !== 'number'){  // in case of ()

      var sum = 0, 
          l = numbers.length;

      numbers.forEach(function(num, i){
        if(i === l-1){
          return;
        } else {
          sum = add(sum, num);
        }
      });

//       console.log(numbers);

      if(numbers.length === 1 && numbers[0] === undefined){
        return undefined;
      } else {
        return sum;        
      }

    } else {  // in case of (n)
      return addValues; // return the function each time so you can apply it to other numbers in the chain 
    }
  }

  return addValues(val);

}

console.log(addg());                // undefined
console.log(addg(2)());             // 2
console.log(addg(2)(7)());          // 9
console.log(addg(3)(0)());          // 7
console.log(addg(1)(2)(4)(8)());    // 15
console.log(addg(5)(4)(-2)());      // 7
```

I would like to know which version is better and why. If you have any suggestions for improving my code, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Your use of `this` in the first implementation is just wrong.  In fact, it won't even work if you run your code in strict mode.  When not in strict mode, `this === window` in the browser.  So, you're just using `window.addToCollection` which is not a particularly good way to do things.  `this` will be set to an object if you use `new SomeFunc()`.

Comment: An array to sum up numbers is a bit of overkill now isn't it? Just keep a running total.

Comment: This is cool, I made a [really similar script some time ago](http://jsfiddle.net/franciscop/xedywca2/) for fun, it might help you shortening your code since it feels overly complicated for me

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia. Hey that looks similar to what I said:)

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia There is a small problem in your code. When you call `sum` function, there should be an empty invocation at the end. like `sum(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)()`. And for this, I see that it is returning `NaN`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First and foremost:

> Anyway, should performance be always the top priority?

Definitely not.  Don't write things that are needlessly unperformant, but only be overly concerned with performance when you have a reason to be.  Most of the time JS execution time is irrelevant, because you're waiting for user interaction, or for a network request, or something else that makes the execution time of the JS pretty unimportant.

I'd be more concerned with writing code that's clear, expressive, and maintainable than performant.

---

Regarding your usage of `this`, though, you definitely shouldn't be using `this` as you are in the first example.  You're leaking into the global scope.  When `addg` is run, what is `this`?  If you were calling `obj.addg()`, `this` would be `obj`, but since you're just calling `addg()`, `this` is the global scope A.K.A. `window` (in the browser).

With your first version if you run this in your console you'll see:

```
addg(); 
//undefined
addToCollection;
//function!  Whoops
```

That's not what you want.  You don't need to assign the internal addToCollection function anywhere, so don't.

---

An `add` function is a bit pointless.  You're adding undefined to the array of numbers in the `()` case, then adding special logic to exclude it from the sum, later, but instead you should just not add undefined at all.  Only do `numbers.push(val)` if `typeof val === 'number'`.

But, then, do you really need to keep an array of numbers at all?

Comment: Wow, I messed `this` up :D Thank you for clearing my understanding about `this`.

Comment: As a way of knowing when `this` is being abused, `'use strict';` helps.

Comment: `this` is better used with `new` constructor, and only in that case will point to an instance of your constructor

Answer (score 22):

You don't need fancy logic.
Good old closure is good enough here.

```
function addg ( left ) {
   if ( left === undefined ) return undefined;
   return function addg_chain ( right ) {
      return right === undefined ? left : ( left += right, addg_chain );
   };
}
```

This simplistic approach creates an execution context, a closure, on the first call, with the parameter `left`.
It will store our current count.

The returned value is a new function that adds to the counter and returns itself, thus preserving the context, until it receives no parameter.

This approach is highly efficient, since only one context and one function is created for each chain, regardless of depth.
But it has the side effect that you can't reuse a partial calculation, because further calculations all share the same context.

e.g.

```
var nine = addg(5)(4);
var ten = nine(1)(); // 10
var twelve = nine(3)(); // Surprise, it is 13!
```

If you need this capability, the solution is also simple:
use a new function, a new closure, for each call.
(Thanks to [200_success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9357/200-success) for the new code.)

```
function addg ( left ) { 
   if ( left === undefined ) return undefined;
   return function addg_chain ( right ) {
      return right === undefined ? left : addg( left + right );
   }
}
```

Creating a new function with each step is obviously a lot less efficient than reusing the same function.
So if you don't need to preserve the state, the first code should be sufficient.

Regardless, closure is still simpler than using object properties and worrying about `this`, don't you think so?
Don't forget to vote up if you agree. :)

> Some programmers commented that these code is hard to understand.
> I assure you that it is just as painful for me to not put them on one line like 200_success's solution, because my [code compression tolerance](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.hk/2008/02/portrait-of-n00b.html) is also pretty high.
>
> I hope to striking a balance between too verbose and too condense.
> Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Your second solution seems too complex. I came up with `function addg(a) { 
    return (a === undefined) ? a : function(b) {
        return (b === undefined) ? a : addg(a + b)
    }
}`

Comment: "*If you need this capability*" - I can't imagine any case where I would not. When programming functional like this, purity has top priority. If you omit it, it will hit you unexpected and hard eventually.

Comment: this is of course opinion, but these solutions seem incredibly unreadable to me.

Comment: This solution is pure, pure spaghetti.

Comment: @Darkhogg: it is only opinion, and yours is wrong.  :-) Seriously, if you take 200_success's solution and format it properly, it has a stark beauty to it and is far more readable (to an experienced programmer) and the proposed alternatives.

Comment: Translating @200_success's solution to ES6 produces the hilariously cryptic `addg = a => a ? b => b ? addg(a + b) : a : a;` - note that this will return a number if `0` is passed as well.

Comment: Technically, you should use `typeof left=='undefined'`,  because otherwise, undefined is only another variable and could equal anything. Put `var undefined='screw you'` at the top of your code and see what happens.

Comment: @Octopus - Perhaps if you're designing toolkit/framework code that many will use in many environments, you might burden your code by protecting it against horrible things people might do like redefine `undefined`, but in normal code, if people want to torture themselves by doing that, I'm perfectly fine if other code breaks.  It's a stupid, wrong thing to do.  They could redefine all sorts of globals too and just break things.  We don't go trying to protect against all that kind of stuff.  And, starting in ES5, the engine is supposed to prevent redefining `undefined` anyway.

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca There is nothing remotely spaghettilike about  parent's solution or 200_success's elegant solution.  You should read this: http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/02/portrait-of-n00b.html

Comment: @Jonah - Spaghetti is in the eye of the beholder (in other words, opinion) so there is no absolute answer there.  I personally do not find this solution very readable or quick to understand or follow.  It's not bad code, just not the easiest to understand in the first glance - particularly the last code block.  Elegance to me means very easy to understand at first glance and otherwise efficiently coded, but no lines of code removed that would serve to make it easier to understand.

Comment: @200_success Thanks for your advise. It is much better than mine.  I have updated the answer.

Comment: Why does `addg_chain` has a name? And why would you call `addg` with a parameter which is never undefined? I assume the call to `addg` was supposed to be a call to `addg_chain`. Why did you miss it?

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca (1) 1st code, `addg_chain` need to return itself, so it needs to be named. 2nd code, it is named for consistency and for easier debug. (2) `addg` may be called without any parameter in the original question, so we need the case. (3) What `addg` does is create and return `addg_chain`. What `add_chain` does is addition or return final value. They do different things.

Comment: @Octopus - Can you offer an example reference of a "stupid wrong" way to use `undefined` that is relevant to this question?  `undefined` is a legitimate value in Javascript (similar to `null`) and can be compared with `===` just like any other value in Javascript.  So, I'm at a loss what "stupid wrong" way you're talking about that is relevant to this question.

Answer (score 12):

Your use of `this` in the first implementation is just wrong. In fact, it won't even work if you run your code in strict mode. When not in strict mode, `this === window` in the browser. So, you're just using `window.addToCollection` which is not a particularly good way to do things.

`this` gets a meaningful value if you call a constructor with the `new` operator or you use `.apply()` or `.call()` or you call `obj.method()`.  Otherwise, it will just be the global object (in regular mode) or `undefined` in strict mode.

I'd suggest this simplification which uses a function closure to store the state of the sum and returns an internal function to allow the chaining.  This is OO-like solution where `addg()` creates a function object that stores the current sum in a private closure and `f()` on the returned function `f` is a means of extracting the sum and `f(val)` is means of adding to it and chaining is supported:

```js
function addg(val) {
    var sum = 0;

    // if you really want addg() all by itself to return undefined
    // instead of 0, you can uncomment this next line
    // if (typeof val === "undefined") return undefined;

    function sumNext(val) {
        if (typeof val === "undefined") {
            return sum;
        } else {
            sum += val;
            return sumNext;
        }
    }
    return sumNext(val);
}

log(addg());
log(addg(2)());
log(addg(2)(7)());
log(addg(3)(0)());
log(addg(1)(2)(4)(8)());
log(addg(5)(4)(-2)());


// logging function
function log(x) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = x;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

This uses a very useful feature in Javascript called a "closure".  When `addg()` returns the inner function `sumNext()`, the code in `sumNext` retains access to the `sum` variable even though `addg()` has already finished executing.  This allows you to privately accumulate the sum with successive calls to `sumNext()` without using any globals.

> Anyway, should performance be always the top priority?

No, performance is never the top priority.  I tend to prioritize things as:

1. **Correct** (produces the desired result)
2. **Reliable** (always produces the desired result)
3. **Robust** (handles errors appropriately and is not brittle when things change around it)
4. **Readable and Maintainable** (try working on someone else's code or even working on your own code 3 years after you wrote it)
5. **Appropriate Performance** (most code does not need to be optimized for performance)

There are times when you work on going for performance, but even then you don't lose sight of the priorities that come before it.

---

Here's a second version that, instead of a closure uses a property of the returned function.  Same results, different way of doing things. This actually exposes the `sum` property as a public property whereas the first version keeps the `sum` hidden in a closure.

```js
function addg(val) {
    function sumNext(val) {
        if (typeof val === "undefined") {
            return sumNext.sum;
        } else {
            sumNext.sum = (sumNext.sum || 0) + val;
            return sumNext;
        }
    }
    return sumNext(val);
}

log(addg());
log(addg(2)());
log(addg(2)(7)());
log(addg(3)(0)());
log(addg(1)(2)(4)(8)());
log(addg(5)(4)(-2)());

// logging function
function log(x) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = x;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

This version is coded to return `undefined` for `addg()`, but that can easily be modified to return `0` if desired (which seems more logical to me).

Comment: `typeof val === "undefined" || !arguments.length` Isn't the `!arguments.length` part redundant? If no arguments are passed then `val` will be `undefined`.

Comment: @PeterOlson - Yes, it was redundant - I removed it.

Comment: Just a little nitpick, you solution isn't Correct. `addg()` produces `0` instead of the expected `undefined`. I like yours better and i think it makes sense to do it that way, but it should be pointed out and perhaps explained why it i better.

Comment: @Tibos - I didn't see any detailed instructions that said it should produce `undefined` (just what the OP's implementation happened to produce) so I used some common sense and picked what I thought was a more intelligent default.  Obviously, the OP can modify one line of code if they wish a different value for that.  I added a commented option in the code if the OP wants that.

Comment: Can you provide a *pure* solution, please? Just to emphasize your points of correctness, reliability and robustness.

Comment: @Bergi - What is a "pure" solution?

Comment: One that doesn't rely on side-effects, like your mutation of the closed-over variable.

Comment: @Bergi - That's not a side-effect.  That's a perfectly valid closure construct in Javascript which is used all the time in Javascript design.  I have no idea what your objection is here.  A new closure is created each time you start a new sequence with `addg()`.  I know you know all this so I'm baffled as to what your objection is.  Is there some requirement from the OP you think I missed?  Or some "good Javascript tenent" you think I've violated?

Comment: `sum +=` is the side effect. The problem is that you only create closures when you "start a sequence", see the "surprise" example in @Sheepy's answer. Better return a new, pure function, that doesn't yield different results when called multiple times.

Comment: It's not strictly a requirement from the OP, but a good functional programming practise :-) If you'd interpret the OP's assignment literally, it would even be fine if you'd place the `sum` outside of the `addg` function; resetting it to `0` with every empty invocation.

Comment: @Bergi - What you're calling a side effect seems like the point of the exercise.  This creates a function object that accumulates a total internally.  Each time it is called, it adds to the prior total.  Anytime you call it with no value, it returns the total stored internally.  It's like `x(val)` is `x.add(val)` and `x()` is `x.getCurrentSum()`.  Do you see anything in the OP's description of the problem that says this behavior is either wrong or undesirable?  Yes, there is an alternative design that behaves differently, but I don't see why that would be either required or more desirable.

Comment: Purity is always desirable :-) It makes code less surprising and error-prone. But I see your point, from an OOP perspective you've just got a mutable instance with some weird chainable methods :-)

Comment: @Bergi - I've modified the description of this solution to describe is an OO solution where `addg()` creates a function object that stores the sum state in a private closure and essentially has two methods (one for retrieving the current sum and one for adding to it).  Hopefully that makes it more clear this is an intended OO design that behaves in a manner consistent with an object with two methods, not as an undesirable side effect.

Comment: 'Correct' and 'Reliable' according to your definitions are not just priorites. If those are ignored then your code is simply broken.

Comment: @Octopus - They are in the list because they are the most important and not to be sacrificed over other things and it is worth pointing that out to some people who get lost in other priorities. Yes, it may seem obvious to some, but in a long software development career, I've seen plenty of code that was neither. For the purposes of this question, the interesting point is how performance is ranked. Only after you've done all the other things and without sacrificing the ones above it, do you work on performance and only if you've tested enough to know that this is really what you should work on.

Comment: @Octopus - See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783510/javascript-how-dangerous-is-it-really-to-assume-undefined-is-not-overwritten on the overwriting of `undefined`.

Answer (score 6):

I am going on a limb here and tell you that both versions look great, but there's some [German Overengineering™](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1510/whats-a-zombie-and-what-are-the-many-other-memes-of-code-review/2520#2520) going on here.

You can easily do this with a variable, a closure and some imagination.

To verify if a value was passed, you can either use `arguments.length` or check if the `value` is `undefined`.
You should prefer `value === undefined` over `arguments.length`, as it can help to limit some optimizations.

But now we have a problem: `undefined` is a global variable, which can be set by **anyone**, **anything** at **any time**.
You can solve that issue by `'use strict';` before the code or by declaring `var undefined;` inside.
I prefer the latter one, since one could run `window.undefined = 5;`, which would cause you to indirectly check and return `5`.
I still recommend adding `'use strict';` since it also adds other basic checks and security features.

Here's my simplified version:

```js
'use strict';
function addg(value) {
    var undefined;

    if(value == undefined)
    {
        return undefined;
    }

    var total = value / 1 || 0;

    var fn = function(value){
        if(value == undefined)
        {
            return total;
        }

        total += value / 1 || 0;

        return fn;
    };

    return fn;
}
```

Proper number handling is left as an exercise.

---

After all, my answer is: Neither! Simplify it.

Comment: `arguments.callee` will not work in strict mode and is generally not recommended because it limits some optimizations that the interpreter can do.

Comment: Douglas Crockford recommended not to use `arguments`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Totally forgot about that. I have added that to the answer.

Comment: @RahulDesai I am really sorry, but I don't know who Douglas Crockford is. But if you want, I can provide a more complete version without `arguments`. It's just that it simplifies your work **so much**.

Comment: I agree with @jfriend00 that `arguments.callee` isn't a good idea.  I agree with @Rahul Desai that `arguments.length` isn't the greatest idea either.  It's better to just check against and use `undefined`.  `undefined = 5` isn't a realistic concern with sane coding (and proper encapsulation against potentially insane external code).

Comment: @Retsam Give me 5

Comment: @Retsam Sorry the delay. I hope it is better now.

Comment: Don't do `var undefined`.  It's unnecessary, a bit confusing, and is protecting against a case that, realistically, should never happen.

Comment: @Retsam You are right, it should **never** happen, but you can't control the user, right? Surelly, it isn't the nicest thing on Earth, but it isn't that confusing. I think.

Answer (score 4):

Just to throw my hat into the ring, I'll propose this:

```
function addg(value) {
  var sum;

  function adder(value) {
    if(typeof value === 'undefined') return sum;
    sum = (sum || 0) + value;
    return adder;
  };

  return adder(value);
}
```

As has already been pointed out, there's no reason to store a collection of numbers; all you need is the previous result. Which calls for a closure.

*Technically* you could argue that calling `addg(undefined)` isn't an *empty* invocation: You're passing in `undefined`, yet it's treated as though you didn't pass anything in. If that's a concern, you can do this instead:

```
function addg(value) {
  var sum;

  function adder(value) {
    if(!arguments.length) return sum;
    sum = (sum || 0) + value;
    return adder;
  };

  return adder.apply(null, [].slice.call(arguments));
}
```

Also, *technically* the `(sum || 0)` would trip on `false`, `NaN` and other false'y values, so for instance `addg(3)(Number.NaN)(3)()` would return 3, since `3 + NaN => NaN`, but the `NaN` gets replaced by zero, meaning you get `0 + 3`. So if *that's* a concern, do this:

```
function addg(value) {
  var sum;

  function adder(value) {
    if(!arguments.length) return sum;
    sum = (typeof sum === 'undefined' ? 0 : sum) + value;
    return adder;
  };

  return adder.apply(null, [].slice.call(arguments));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since @Retsam did a good job at explaining `this` for what you are doing, I would like to show a much simpler way to create `addg` that is quite fast.

```
function addg( arg ) {
    // If arg cannot be interpreted as a number then process the data collected.
    // Note: Can change to ->
    // if(arg === undefined) {
    // or if need to just look for empty arguments...
    // if(!arguments.length) {
    if(isNaN(arg = +arg)) {
        // Temp storage.
        var sum = addg.sum;
        // Resets the function.
        // Can also do ->
        // addg.sum = undefined;
        delete addg.sum;
        // Returns the sum collected.
        return sum;
    }
    // Checks to see if addg has sum yet.
    addg.sum = (addg.sum) ? addg.sum + arg : arg;
    // Returns the function for more args.
    return addg;
};
```

---

Some examples:

```
addg();       // => undefined
addg(1)();    // => 1
addg(1)(2)(); // => 3
addg(0)();    // => 0

// Invocation of addg
addg(1);
// Another invocation of addg...
addg(1);
// Empty invocation so return sum!
addg(); // => 2
```

Comment: Call `addg(1)` several times (which returns the function). Then call `addg(1)()`. What do you get?

Comment: @Octopus. You get the desired behavior. The question says "write a function `addg` that adds from many invocations, until it sees an empty invocation." So, if you invoke the function `addg(1)` then `addg(1)()` you should get `2` because `addg` is supposed to add up every invocation until an empty invocation occurs:) Unless somewhere it states specifically that is wrong please point that out:)